# Featuretools: Using features calculated in train data on new data

Tags: python-3.x, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, featuretools

I was wondering how to use features developed in train time for prediction on new data. The dataset in question is the appointment cancellation dataset from [Predict appointment no show, Github](https://github.com/Featuretools/predict-appointment-noshow/blob/master/Tutorial.ipynb)

Consider the feature `locations.PERCENT_TRUE(no_show)`: the percentage of past appointment cancellations at a given location. Let us say I have new incoming test data with the same locations as in train data for which I already know these values. How can I use this feature in test data? Of course I can merge the test data to the train data and recalculate all the features using `featuretools.dfs()` but that is time consuming.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, merging the test data to the train data is not required. You can reuse the feature definitions on the incoming test data. For example, when you use DFS on the train data, the feature definitions which include `locations.PERCENT_TRUE(no_show)` are returned along with the feature matrix.

```py
fm, features = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es_train,
    target_entity='appointments',
    ...
)
```

On the test data, you can create the entity set and reuse the definitions to calculate the features.

```py
fm = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(
    features=features,
    entityset=es_test,
    ...
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Can you explain how this works. If I am right `features` variable is a list of strings of feature definitions. How does the second function know the values of features computed at train time?

Comment: The feature definitions are derived from a `FeatureBase` object that can be serialized / deserialized with the necessary metadata for reconstructing the feature. By using the feature definition objects, the second function can reconstruct the features and apply them on the new entity set. [This page in the documentation](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/guides/deployment.html#deployment) has more information about using feature definitions.